# How to post data in SOAP web service

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

I have following XML in which i want to post record in **ProductNumber**, **Quantity**, **Price**.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <QueryPrices xmlns="xyz">
      <strSessionKey>string</strSessionKey>
      <nDiscountID>int</nDiscountID>
      <objOrderItems>
        <OrderItem>
          <ProductNumber>int</ProductNumber>
          <Quantity>int</Quantity>
          <Price>float</Price>
        </OrderItem>
        <OrderItem>
          <ProductNumber>int</ProductNumber>
          <Quantity>int</Quantity>
          <Price>float</Price>
        </OrderItem>
      </objOrderItems>
    </QueryPrices>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Soap object, and just use `addProperty()` to pass parameter.

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
request .addProperty("key", value);
```

Dealing with [SOAP](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-ksoap2-android-and-parsing-output-data)

in your case:

```
request.addProperty( "ProductNumber","something");
request.addProperty( "Quantity","something");
request.addProperty( "Price","something");
```

Comment: As per your answer i have posted the strSessionKey and  nDiscountID. But i want to enter values in ProductNumber, ProductNumber, Quantity, Price. which is in objOrderItems tag.

Comment: I got following exception after using this codeW/System.err(1411): SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Server' faultstring: 'Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@44f75908